# Потоки (Наверное, дело в них)

Tags: winapi, многопоточность, c++

<<Программа по общению с ком портом>>

Вот в чем суть проблемы-Когда запускаю программу и пошагово её выполняю(f10 в Вижуал студио), то порт отлично открывается и происходит запись. когда просто запускаю программу-она не выполняется. Виснет не выполняется функция WriteFile(...). Причем не выдает никакой ошибки, просто программа перестает что либо делать.

Пытался перед этой функцией вставить разного рода паузы(Sleep,getch(), cin, etc.), между открытием порта и WriteFile(), но в этом случае программа не работает даже при пошаговом выполнении.

Пытался сделать оконное приложение-одна кнопка открывает порт, другая записывает. Порт открывается, но когда нажимаю записать-программа зависает.

Требуется, что бы программа выполнялась НЕ только при пошаговом выполнении!
помогите пожалуйста, с решением проблемы.

А вот код программы:

> ```
>  int main()
> {     
>       /* .... */
>
>     char sPortName[] = "COM5";
>
>     open_port(sPortName);// сперва открываем порт
>     write_scc((void*) TextOut,a,b);// запись в порт   
>     /*....*/
> }
>
> void open_port(char * name) {
>   hCom = CreateFile(name, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL,
> OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);//(имя порта,
> права доступа,0,0) -открытие порта, с указанием прав
>
> if (hCom == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)// если порт
> ```
>
> открыт ошибкой(порт не открыт)
>       {
>             cout << " *** Error opening port!\n";
>             getch();
>             return;
>       }
>
> else
>       {
>             cout << " *** Port succesfully opened!\n";
>
> ```
>         GetCommState(hCom, &dcb);//Функция GetCommState извлекает
> // данные о текущих настройках
> // управляющих сигналов для указанного
> // коммуникационного устройства.
>
>         dcb.BaudRate = CBR_9600;
>         dcb.ByteSize = 8;
>         dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;
>         dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
>
>         if (SetCommState(hCom, &dcb))
>               cout << " *** Configuring OK.\n\n";
>         else
>               cout << " *** Configuring error.\n\n";
>
>         hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, ReadThread, (LPVOID)hwnd, 0, 0);
>
>   } }
>
> bool write_scc(LPCVOID outputData,
>                  const unsigned int& sizeBuffer,
>                  unsigned long& length)    {   if (&length)   {
>
> if (WriteFile(hCom, // handle to file to write to
>
>   outputData,              // pointer to data to write to file
>
>   sizeBuffer,              // number of bytes to write
>
>   &length,NULL) == 0)      // pointer to number of bytes written
>  {
>   printf("Reading of serial communication has problem.");
>
>   return FALSE;
>
> }
> return TRUE;   }
> ```
>
> return FALSE; }

Comment: кто знает, может Ваш ReadThread блокирует всю запись...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А к ком-порту что нибудь подключено? Если нет, то будете вечно ждать ReadFile или WriteFile. Нужно как минимум воткнуть заглушку, чтобы TX попадало на RX этого же порта. И порт настроить на полудуплех. И открывать порт с флагом `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`. И юзать OVERLAPPED структуру в ReadFile и WriteFile. По крайней мере, мне таким способом удалось слушать микроконтроллер, висящим на ком-порту. Довольно странный способ обмена данными между потоками.